# Entity Framework foreign key issues when inserting multiple records?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-4

We are running into an issue where when we submit a list of several objects to be added to the database we get errors related to foreign keys...

```
using (context ctx = new context()
{
    foreach(foo f in bars)
    {
         ctx.AddToFoo(f);
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

the error says that the insert statement conflicts with the foreign key constraints but if I move the `SaveChanges()` inside the `foreach` loop it works fine but it seems that it would be much slower...

I would roll this into the `BulkCopy` class but we have a bunch of logging code tied to `SaveChanges`.

Edit:
here is a link to a picture of the exception [Linky](http://www.flickr.com/photos/67246079@N00/6510885421/)

Comment: Care to share the error? Also might be worth firing up SQL Profiler or EFProf to take a look at the actual SQL being issued so you can see if its trying to do anything in the wrong order.

Comment: I only have a print out of it so Im trying to get a pic of the exception uploaded...

Comment: ok how about this [Link To Pic](http://www.flickr.com/photos/67246079@N00/6510885421/)

Comment: Does Foo have any foreign keys on it? What is the full exception message? I ask because the name of the foreign key constraint is usually referenced (e.g. constraint "FK_Teacher_Class")

Comment: Yes it has foreign keys on it and see the pic above for the full exception

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `SaveChanges` doesn't save each foo in the same order that they are added in  `AddToFoo`.

Comment: Each foo is unrelated to the others foriegn key wise so that shouldnt be it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it would work inside the for loop. If there is an exception outside the loop then it should also give an exception inside.

You should troubleshoot the foreign key constraint listed in the exception. So, if the constraint is "FK_Foo_Parent" then you need to have a Parent item first that the Foo item references.

Your code should look like this:

```
                using (context ctx = new context())
                {
                    ctx.AddToParents(parent);

                    foreach (foo f in bars)
                    {
                        parent.Foos.Add(f);
                        ctx.AddToFoos(f);
                    }
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
```

That will setup the Foreign Key references between the new foo record and its parent record.

Comment: I was thinking that it might have something to do with adding too many objects before calling SaveChanges but I guess I will have to take a look at the SQL its generating because the foreign keys should all be fine at that point